# average of a value between two dates

Tags: sql, average

hi i have three columns in a database and sample data is below:

```
date, sample, weight
01/01/15, sample1, 80
01/02/15, sample1, 90
01/03/15, sample1, 95
01/04/15, sample1, 83
01/01/15, sample2, 82
01/02/15, sample2, 91
01/03/15, sample2, 95
01/04/15, sample2, 85
```

I want to average the weight column when the sample date is between certain dates such as 01/01/15 and 01/02/15 per sample.

I would like to write this in an SQL query

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a pretty basic query using `avg()` and `where`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
SELECT AVG(weight)
FROM mytable
WHERE date_column BETWEEN '01/01/2015' AND '01/04/2015'
```